# Exported graphic resolution in ArgoUML

Tags: uml, argouml

Is there a way to control the resolution of an exported PNG image in ArgoUML?

Can't find any way to create a higher resolution output and the default resolution of exported grpahics is not useable for importing and printing them within a document for most UMLs we've created so far - most labels and annotations are barely readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**D'Oh!**

On second (3rd..) look it turns out that there's a setting under *Environment*:
When setting the *Graphics Export Resolution* to **High** all is good!

Which that was the default..

Answer (score 3):

The PNG exporter writes at screen resolution (~75-100 dpi) which will look quite small at print resolutions (300+ dpi).  You can have your document tool scale the image up, which will look kind of chunky, but will probably be usable, or you can choose a vector format which is more appropriate for printing than a raster format like PNG or GIF.

ArgoUML supports both SVG and EPS which would probably be better choices depending on what your document editor/processor accepts.

Comment: Hmm - importing to LaTeX right now so I've tried EPS, which was unusable (lines and other stuff missing).

Comment: Scaling up's not really an option since the labels are barely readable consisting of 'pixel clouds'. Controlling the export resolution would be awesome.. wonder if this is an outstanding bug/CR?